# How to add and subtract numbers via JavaScript in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add numbers in `<td></td>` below via JavaScript. For example using the following description:

`<td id='last'>` + formatNumber(data.tickers[key].last) + `</td>
<td id='high'>` + formatNumber(data.tickers[key].high) + `</td>
<td id='low'>` + formatNumber(data.tickers[key].low) + `</td>`

How do I change the text of table data elements via JavaScript?

`<td id='new1'> = + <td id='last'> + <td id='high'> + </td>
<td id='new2'> = + <td id='high'> + <td id='loww'> + </td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm going to make your life a bit easier. Instead of using `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[3].getElementsByTagName('td')[2]` to get the fourth `tr` element's third `td` element ([0] = first, [2] = third, etc) this will help make your code much *much* easier to read. You don't need `id` attributes on every element if you know how reliable code and order are by default.

```
function tag_(t)
{//Example: tag_('body')[0];
 return (document.getElementsByTagName(t)) ? document.getElementsByTagName(t) : false;
}

Object.prototype.tag_ = function(t)
{//Example: id_('unique_id').tag_('td')[0];
 return (this.getElementsByTagName && this.getElementsByTagName(t) && this.getElementsByTagName(t).length > 0) ? this.getElementsByTagName(t) : false;
}
```

Secondly the easiest way to *both* read *and* write data to *any* element is to use `textContent`.

Read the fourth `td` on the third `tr`:

```
//Read an element's text node:
console.log(tag_('tr')[2].tag_('td')[5].textContent);

//Write to an element's text node:
tag_('table')[0].tag_('tr')[2].tag_('td')[5].textContent = '1,234');
```

JavaScript is a bit strict when it comes to types. So if you need to do some math with text content that you just *read* you need to convert it:

```
Number(tag_('tr')[1].tag_('td')[5].textContent);//'123' becomes `123`
Number(tag_('tr')[2].tag_('td')[2].textContent);//'a123' becomes `NaN` (Not a Number)
```

If I recall correctly I recently used the following to strip non-numeric text from a string:

```
var my_number = Number('String or replace with object reference'.replace(/\D/g,''));
```

Now that you're getting the read/write aspects and overcoming some of the more oddities associated with it I'll iterate over...iteration! You may already know this though I'm presuming a *full* answer is more desirable than a partial answer for not just you though also others reading this in the [future](https://youtu.be/yX2d-Va7Vz0?t=35s).

```
var table = tag_('table');

for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
{
 console.log(table[i]);
 var tr = table[i].tag_('tr');//Whatever table[i] is and it's table rows.

 for (var j = 0; j < tr[i].length; j++)
 {
  console.log(tr[j]);
  var td = table[i].tag_('tr')[j].tag_('td');//All the table data elements.

  for (var k = 0; k < td.length; k++)
  {
   //apply read/write conditions here.
   //potentially call a second global function to keep your code reusable.
  }
 }
}
```

That should help you get far enough with specific and iteral targeting of table data elements to help you learn and achieve your goals.

Comment: magical, like writing on light. truly enlightenment that is extraordinary and reasonable to understand and learn. I then tried your translation in JavaScript and it was amazing. the results are exactly and the same in each table. thank you for sharing.

Comment: @borneo Glad to have been helpful. Whenever you get stuck go "up" in the code and use `console.log(my_object);` to grant you more insight. :-)

Comment: but am stuck in here: `<td>` + formatNumber(data.tickers[key].high) + `</td>
  <td>` + formatNumber(data.tickers[key].low) + `</td>
  <td>` + jumlahkan + `</td> function jumlahkan() {
 a=eval(data.tickers[key].last)
 b=eval(data.tickers[key].low)
 c=a+b
}` Its error!!

Comment: @borneo I don't know where that original code comes from. I highly recommend staying *away* from `eval()`. I would `console.log(key)`, `console.log(data)`, `console.log(data.tickers)`, `console.log(data.tickers[key])`, `console.log(data.tickers[key].high)` and `console.log(formatNumber(data.tickers[key].high))` in example. It looks like it wants to format a number...is it getting a `typeof object` Number or string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
// these target the cell elements
let last = document.getElementById("last");
let high = document.getElementById("high");
let low = document.getElementById("low");

let new1 = document.getElementById("new1");
let new2 = document.getElementById("new2");

// now we convert cell content to numbers, add them and make them 2 decimal places.
new1.textContent = (parseFloat(last.textContent) + parseFloat(high.textContent)).toFixed(2);

new2.textContent = (parseFloat(high.textContent) + parseFloat(low.textContent)).toFixed(2);
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>last</th>
<th>high</th>
<th>low</th>
<th>new1</th>
<th>new2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='last'> 23.40 </td>
<td id='high'> 28.20 </td>
<td id='low'> 22.10 </td>
<td id='new1'></td>
<td id='new2'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```